# How to resolve this error E / libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write error: Operation not allowed?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

everybody
I noticed an error in my application log

E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

It is triggered when you switch from the map Activity to another activity (for example, when you click the "back" arrow on the emulator)
, while the application does not crash and works as intended.
For the sake of interest, I downloaded another application with Google maps from the Internet and changed only the API KEY in it to my own
And he has the same error in the log with the same actions.

Question: What kind of error is this and how to remove it.

On one of the forums I saw the solution, it did not help, the error is still displayed (but at least it does not crash until I did the following something else and the message "System UI does not respond"

From

Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"@string/API_KEY");
To

Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(),YOUR API KEY)

Comment: why do you care though ? it's not a crash or anything, maybe it's just something inside the library ?